# White space in my response text (request wp7, response php)

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, response, whitespace

Hy!
I'm sending a request from wp7 to php. When php sends its response, the response received by the WP7 app contains a lot of white space character and newline(s).

Here is my WP7 response callback:

```
void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = asynchronousResult.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult) as HttpWebResponse;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.WriteLine(responseText);
                SaveResponseText(responseText);                  
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
        }
    }
```

And here is my php code detail:

```
if ($_POST["event"] == "riaszt")
  {
if($count != 0)
{         
    {
      echo ok;

    } 
}
 }
```

Comment: Try using trim() for the returned data

Comment: user1520209 : Please read your own question once. find how many mistakes you made ? Dont write everything in hurry ,if we answer in hurry it may double your work

Comment: you either have to write `echo "ok";` or `echo $ok;` depending on what's right for your situation.

Comment: I'm tried trim, split, and its works, but not all whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know if that help you but, for all response's servor i use this code =>

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    // End the operation
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    Debug.WriteLine("response ==> [" + responseString + "]");
```

But, your code is Ok, have you sure your servor send a response? when you call your url in browser have you a response ? 
maybe is an ancoding problem...